# Где найти хорошую статью о различиях движков в mysql

Tags: mysql

Не могу найти нигде , кроме как на doc.mysql. Может кто-то встречался с данной проблемой?

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как вопроса не по теме, потому что вопросы опросники запрещены в сообществе.

Answer (score 1):

Замечательная статья [здесь](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-engines.html) сравнение , описание и т.д.
[или тут на крайняк](http://habrahabr.ru/post/64851/)